# Multiple nesting in Falcor query

Tags: falcor

I am trying to query a multiple nested object with Falcor. I have an `user` which has beside other the value `follower` which itself has properties like `name`.

I want to query the name of the `user` and the first 10 `follower`.

My Falcor server side can be seen on GitHub there is my [router](https://github.com/inovex/falcor-github-example/blob/master/server/server.js) and [resolver](https://github.com/inovex/falcor-github-example/blob/master/server/data/resolver.js).

I query the user with `user["KordonDev"]["name", "stars"]`. And the follower with `user["KordonDev"].follower[0.10]["name", "stars"]`.

The route for follower is `user[{keys:logins}].follower[{integers:indexes}]` but this doesn't catch the following query.

I tried to add it as string query. 
`user["KordonDev"]["name", "stars", "follower[0..10].name"]` doesn't work.

The second try was to query with arrays of keys. `["user", "KordonDev", "follower", {"from":0, "to":10}, "name"]` but here I don't know how to query the name of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know and looking on the [path parser](https://github.com/Netflix/falcor-path-syntax/blob/master/test/parse-tree/parser.spec.js). There is no way to do nested queries.

What you want to do is [batch](https://netflix.github.io/falcor/doc/Model.html#batch) the query and do two queries.

```
user["KordonDev"]["name", "stars"]
user["KordonDev"]["follower"][0..10].name
```

It seems that falcor does not support this, there is even a somewhat [old issue](https://github.com/Netflix/falcor/issues/67#issuecomment-91089776) discussing how people trying to do nested queries.

> to the point about the current syntax leading people to try this:
>
> ['lolomo', 0, 0, ['summary', ['item', 'summary']]]
>
> I can see folks trying to do the same thing with the new syntax:
>
> "lolomo[0][0]['summary', 'item.summary']"
>
> As soon as they know they can do:
>
> "lolomo[0][0]['summary', 'evidence']"

So it seems deep nested queries is not a functionality.